# c# Foreach vs Linq looping?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, performance, linq

What are the main differences between a Foreach looping and LINQ looping?

which one has better performance, and what they disadvantages.

i have two different examples that produce the same result :

```
foreach(var countryItem in input.availableCountries) {
    var ddlItem = new ListItem();
    ddlItem.Text = countryItem.Value;
    ddlItem.Value = countryItem.Key;
    ddlNationalityCountry.Items.Add(ddlItem);
}
```

and

```
ddlNationalityCountry.Items.AddRange(input.availableCountries.Select(
    item => new ListItem { 
        Text = item.Value,
        Value = item.Key
    }).ToArray());
```

which one should i use?

Comment: what do you think linq uses ?

Comment: If you want to know which is faster try both ways and find out. As to which you should use - the version that you find most readable and easy to maintain.

Comment: What research and testing have you done to investigate what these two are doing and how they are different?  Of this, what have you understood and what have you not understood?

Comment: i know that linq makes the same foreach, but for some reasen they both exist. And i want to know main diferences and maybe some tricky stuff about them.

Comment: In this case, there's not going to be a lot of difference. You can write test code to see which is actually faster, but I doubt any difference is going to be significant. Linq isn't magic and can't avoid having to visit every item in your list, so both are going to be `O(n)`. As to why they both exist, Linq gives you a different and more expressive syntax. In this case, again, it doesn't make a lot of difference, but in more complex cases it can be a lot cleaner to write linq rather than a `foreach` full of a lot of condition checking.

Comment: Using LINQ  is nonsense in this case. I am a big fan of LINQ, but if i'd see this code i'd cringe.

Comment: @AntonSelin: This [blog post](http://www.schnieds.com/2009/03/linq-vs-foreach-vs-for-loop-performance.html) might help too.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is a small amount of overhead for linq operators. Typically, this overhead is **not** driving performance for the application. Additionally, the overhead buys you the ability to much more easily create efficiency elsewhere.

Some of that efficiency is for the programmer: cleaner code, fewer bugs, easier maintenance. Some of the efficiency is in making it easier to build faster algorithms.

What I mean by this is that your first sample is adding items to a collection. Your second sample is producing an array. Why are you creating that array? I know you need it for the function call, but in most other scenarios, you won't. Linq allows you to think in terms of a pipeline for your collection, where the end result is never fully realized until the final step, and each step along the way only acts on those elements that are relevant, thus often saving a *lot* more computer time or ram than the linq overhead would cost you.

If you just use linq to write the same things you'd do with a foreach, linq is going to be a (small!) net performance loss (but probably still a net productivity win). If you learn to embrace what linq can do, linq can be a big net performance win.

Comment: The main difference between foreach and a linq statement is that one is like PASCAL and the other is like HASKELL... :)

Comment: @Alexander: both have their place in C#, a `foreach` is more appropriate if you want to modify,add,delete something and LINQ is more readable if you want to query something(in terms of _read something_). In this case OP has already all he needs to add it to the `DropDownList`: `input.availableCountries`. So no need to use LINQ.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: `a foreach is more appropriate if you want to modify,add,delete something`: Only you can't add or delete from a collection you are iterating over.

Comment: @MattBurland: _something_ was meant as to something else. In this case the `DropDownList`'s `Items`.

Comment: @MattBurland First off, that's not technically true.  Some collection explicitly break their iterators when the collections are modified.  Many don't.  Some can even work correctly when being iterated while being mutated. Additionally, for those with this behavior, you can still modify the collection when you aren't iterating over it, but rather something else.